# Document with nothing but floats gives unexpected output when using Babel

Tags: babel

I'm writing a document with only floats (tables and figures) in it and I'm having trouble compiling. The problem seems to be the `babel` package, as testified by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
X
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
Y
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this MWE with `pdflatex`, I get a pdf document with nothing but four apostrophes (seemingly two for each float). If I remove the line `\usepackage{babel}`, then I get the expected X and Y. I tried both the `spanish` and `ngerman` options for `babel` but it didn't make  any difference.

I'm using the TeX Live 2019 version that comes packaged with Ubuntu 20.04.

Am I missing something here?

Edit: log file, as requested:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.7.25)  31 JUL 2020 16:00
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**babel_MWE.tex
(./babel_MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2020/02/14 3.40 The Babel package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2020/02/14 3.40 Babel switching mechanism
)
Package babel Info: You haven't specified a language. I'll use 'nil'
(babel)             as the main language. Reported on input line 572.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/nil.ldf
Language: nil 2020/02/14 3.40 Nil language

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2020/02/14 3.40 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count175
\U@D=\dimen135

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count176
)
\l@nil=\language85
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count177
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
(./babel_MWE.aux)
\openout1 = `babel_MWE.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
Missing character: There is no ü in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no û in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ú in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ù in font cmr10!
 [1


{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Missing character: There is no ü in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no û in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ú in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ù in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ü in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no û in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ú in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no ù in font cmr10!

Overfull \vbox (10.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []


(./babel_MWE.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 958 strings out of 481239
 14416 string characters out of 5920377
 255236 words of memory out of 5000000
 16292 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,19p,165b,99s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on babel_MWE.pdf (1 page, 8802 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: works ok in texlive 2020.

Comment: please show the log file that you get for that example

Comment: I get X and Y with texlive2018, 2019, 2020

Comment: `Missing character: There is no ü in font cmr10!` why is it trying to typeset  ü  ??

Comment: I tried compiling my MWE on a different computer with Ubuntu 20.04 / TeX Live 2019 and got the same result, so I guess my installation is not corrupted or something.

Comment: can you email me babel_MWE.tex ? d dot p dot carlisle at gmail dot com

Comment: The problem seems to occur every time there is a page with nothing but a float on it, which is a real issue in many cases. I'll try to install vanilla TeX Live 2020 to see if it goes away. As far as I can tell, this is a problem with the TeX Live 2019 version that comes packaged with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: So, on Ubuntu 20.04, what should I do to avoid this problem?
And, by the way, is there a lightweight way to switch languages w/o using babel?
Thanks