# float too high results in failed output

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, texlive, babel

I encountered a wired behavior with my floats. I am running tex-live 2019 on ubuntu 20.04.
Running the following with pdflatex, resulst in some ,,, instead of the figure.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,twoside,DIV=14,numbers=noenddot,headinclude]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.25cm,y=1.25cm]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle node {1} (6,1);
  \filldraw[fill=lightgray] (0,1) rectangle node {2} (2,2);
  \draw (2,1) rectangle node {2} (4,2);
  \draw (4,1) rectangle node {2} (6,2);
  \draw (0,2) rectangle node {3} (1.5,3);
  \draw (1.5,2) rectangle node {3} (3.5,3);
  \draw (3.5,2) rectangle node {3} (5,3);
  \draw (5,2) rectangle node {\dots} (6,3);
  \draw (0,3) rectangle node {4} (6,4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Some boxes}
  
\end{figure}
  
\end{document}
```

Removing the babel package than everything works fine. Since I actually want to use babel any idea of fixing this would be appreciated.
The only strange massage in the log is

```
[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!
 [2

]
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!

Overfull \vbox (11.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []

 [3

]
```

PS: A friend of mine tested it on his miktex on windows and there erverything works fine.

PPS:
I did a sudo apt purge texlive-* and a complete new install. So I assume everything should be how it is supposed to be.

Comment: Running on up to date TeXLive 2020 on Ubuntu, no warnings. Are you sure your installation is complete?

Comment: I assume it is the same problem as discript here. Was unable to find it half an hour ago ;-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556901/document-with-nothing-but-floats-gives-unexpected-output-when-using-babel so I may have to install tex-live2020 by hand

Comment: I don't seem to get any similar warnings using TeXLive 2019 either. Might be an idea to add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and post the package list (including versions) in your question. Then it is easier to compare.