# Conflict between babel and graphicx (Tex Live 2019/Debian)

Tags: floats, babel

I have a very strange behavior with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{normal_dichte}
  \caption{Dichten von Normalverteilungen} \label{fig:normal}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{exponential_dichte}
  \caption{Dichten von Exponentialverteilungen}\label{fig:exponential}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering  \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{chi_3}
  \caption{Dichten einer $\chi^2$-Verteilung}\label{fig:chi}
\end{figure}
Abbildungen~\ref{fig:normal},~\ref{fig:exponential} und~\ref{fig:chi}.
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, the third picture is not included, and `\ref{fig:chi}` is reported as an undefined reference. I get the following output:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `problem2' with ``pdflatex -synctex=1  -file-line-error    problem2.tex'' 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./problem2.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./problem2.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:chi' on page 1 undefined on input line 19.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./normal_dichte.png> <./
exponential_dichte.png>] [2]
Overfull \vbox (10.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
(./problem2.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

The problem goes away if I do any one of the following three things:

1. Comment out `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. The first two pictures are on page 1, and the third picture is on page 2, and there is no problem with the references.
2. Reduce the widths to `.4\textwidth`. Then all three pictures fit on one page and the problem disappears.
3. I also tried Tex Live 2021 on Overleaf, and there the original code compiles just fine.

Is there a way to get the original code to work without changing my Tex Live version?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Assuming that the version of `babel` is contemporaneous with the version of LaTeX (2020-02-02), there have been quite a few updates to `babel` since then, including one to `babel-german` (2020/07/30), so that might be the cause of the problem.  Retrieving the latest `babel` from CTAN and placing it in the directory from which you're running the job (so that you don't lose the "master" version) might help; on the other hand it might not, if the latest `babel` depends on something changed in the core.  But you *don't* want to lose the existing version of `babel`.

Comment: Thanks, Barbara. For the minimal example, putting the latest babel into the working directory does indeed fix the issue. But for the larger project in which the problem occurs this creates a lot of new errors (so probably the new babel does not work well with the old core). Perhaps I'll just have to install TexLive 2021.

Comment: graphicx has nothing to do with it. You are loosing a complete float, and it works again if you change the sizes slightly. Try if it works if you use `[htbp]` and so allow float pages.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike. Without the reference to graphicx I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/556901/document-with-nothing-but-floats-gives-unexpected-output-when-using-babel I guess I will just try to avoid pages with nothing but a float.